# Material UI TableSortLabel - show custom IconComponent only on hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using custom `IconComponent` for `TableSortLabel` (material-ui). I want to show the icon only on hover. Can anyone advice on how this can be done?

Below is my code

```
 const DropdownIndicator = (props) => (
        <div {...props.innerProps} className={classes.dropdown}>
            <ArrowDropUpIcon viewBox= "1 -9 24 24" className={classes.arrowDropUp}/>
            <ArrowDropDownIcon viewBox="1 9 24 24" className={classes.arrowDropDown}/>
        </div>
    );
```

```
<TableSortLabel
  active={orderBy === propertyName}
  direction={orderBy === propertyName ? sortDirection : "asc"}
  onClick={() => onSort(propertyName)}
  hideSortIcon={orderBy === propertyName}
  IconComponent={DropdownIndicator}
>{text}</TableSortLabel>
```

I want the `IconComponent` to be shown only on hover. Unfortunately, `hideSortIcon` property is not working when it has custom `IconComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is, assuming you already have a class with `makeStyles` or `withStyles` defined above that have the `:hover` effect, since `IconComponent` takes in a React Component, you can just pass in a `className` prop like below:

```js
<TableSortLabel
 active={orderBy === propertyName}
 direction={orderBy === propertyName ? sortDirection :"asc"}
 onClick={() => onSort(propertyName)}
 hideSortIcon={orderBy === propertyName}
 IconComponent={() => <DropdownIndicator className={classes.displayOnHover} />}>
  {text}
</TableSortLabel>
```

And in your `DropdownIndicator`, you can take this value out from prop and just concatenate the class name with the one you already have for the icon that you want to apply those effects like this:

```js
const DropdownIndicator = (props) => (
        <div {...props.innerProps} className={`${classes.dropdown} ${props.className}`}>
            <ArrowDropUpIcon viewBox= "1 -9 24 24" className={classes.arrowDropUp}/>
            <ArrowDropDownIcon viewBox="1 9 24 24" className={classes.arrowDropDown}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: @TungPhan awesome this works perfectly. one more question, I have several TableSortLabel elements in my table, so there are multiple custom icons (DropdownIndicator's). What I have to do is show only the DropdownIndicator that hover is on. Hence, I have implemented react usestate on (onMouseOver, onMouseOut)for TableSortLabel. But whats happening is when I hovered on any of the column headers, it is hiding/unhiding all the Dropdown's at the same time. I just want to hide/unhide only the DropdownIndicator that belongs to the columnheader hover is on Any idea on how this can be achieved please?

Comment: @menan can you have a Codepen or somewhere that has your code? Since describing like this is very vague and I think there are many factors that contribute to your issue.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was vague. I managed to get it working by adding few checks. Here is the Codepen link (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-x81b0?file=/demo.js) that demonstrates just incase if you like to take a look

Comment: is it me or you already fixed the issue? when I visited your link and hover on one column's header, I see that the icon is only hiding/unhiding for that column only and not for the rest.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue later after posting the comment. Thank you very much for helping :)